# Unicode characters do not appear in IEEE style bibliography

Tags: biblatex, unicode, biber

I cannot get Unicode characters to appear in the IEEE style bibliography with `biblatex` and `biber`. Shown below are minimal working examples.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[style=ieee, bibencoding=utf8, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\addbibresource{Bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{lee12b}
\renewcommand*{\UrlFont}{\rmfamily}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

And here are the contents of the `.bib` file. Note the following Unicode characters: µ (Greek mu) and ° (degree sign).

```
% Bibliography.bib
@article{lee12b,
    Author = {Lee, Junghyup and Cho, SeongHwan},
    Date-Added = {2013-01-23 07:05:03 +0800},
    Date-Modified = {2013-02-11 13:58:24 +0800},
    Doi = {10.1109/JSSC.2012.2204475},
    Issn = {0018-9200},
    Journal = {Solid-State Circuits, IEEE Journal of},
    Month = {Oct},
    Number = {10},
    Pages = {2527--2533},
    Printed = {1},
    Title = {{A 1.4-µW 24.9-ppm/°C Current Reference With Process-Insensitive Temperature Compensation in 0.18-µm CMOS}},
    Volume = {47},
    Year = {2012},
    }
```

Comment: (1) Try to add `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`. (2) If that doesn't help, please check whether the special character are in the file generated by `biber`.

Comment: And just now found: `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}` instead of `[utf]` seems to accept both `mu` and `degree`.

Comment: @tohecz I remember egreg commenting in one of my previous answers about a conflict between `utf8x` option and `biblatex`. I don't know what conflict though.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and looked up the `.bbl` file. Yes, I see the mu and degree characters in their actual appearance (not Unicode numbers). But still they don't show up in the output PDF.

Comment: `utf8x` messes it up with stuff like `[PleaseinsertprerenderUnicode...]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is inputenc - this doesn't cover the full range of UTF-8. If you change the inputenc line to

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
```

and then use Lualatex or Xelatex instead of PDFlatex, your example works fine.

The other option is to keep your example as it is and use pdflatex as normal but add:

```
\usepackage{textcomp}
```

and run biber like this:

```
biber --output_safecharsset=full --output_safechars <file.bcf>
```

which will convert the difficult characters which inputenc can't deal with into TeX macros. The textcomp package loads the macro definitions to deal with the macros which biber converts to (in this case, the `\textdegree` macro).

Comment: Is there a way to do this while still using `pdflatex`? Using other `--latex` flavors could potentially spawn a host of other problems, especially that I'm using the `IEEEtran` document class.

Comment: Yes, I updated the answer with a pdflatex solution too.