# biblatex: title won't show up correctly

Tags: biblatex, biber

I use `biblatex` and `biber` to include a bibliography based on a .bib-file. I print the title in the bibliography based on the biblatex-instruction `\printfield{title}`. Unfortunatley, the title shows up incorrectly sometimes. A few examples:
- `title = {ECU firmware}` in the .bib-file results in `ECU rmware`
- `title = {Nice temperature of 25°C}` results in `Nice temperature of 25C`

In the biblatex-documentation I found:

> `\printfield[hformati]{hfieldi}`
>
> This command prints a hfieldi using the formatting directive hformati , as defined
>   with \DeclareFieldFormat . ...

So ist the formatting directive for the title field the problem? Can I change it in order to get the expected result?

Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{bibfile.bib}
@newtype{xxx,
  title   = {ECU ﬁrmware},
  author  = {author1},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\addbibresource{bibfile.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{newtype}{
    \usebibmacro{begentry}
    \printnames{author}
    \newunit\newblock
    \printfield{title}
    \usebibmacro{finentry}
}

\begin{document}
See~\cite{xxx}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

results in:

[image]

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Can you give us a MWE?

Comment: [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407)

Comment: The problem is, that `ﬁ` is not written as individual letters in your bib file, but as a ligature, a composed letter. Delete it and retype `fi`

Comment: I guess the same holds true for the missing degree sign. Delete it and replace it with and appropriate tex syntax (a quick hack being `$^\circ$`, but there are better ways).

Comment: You may can use `\textcelsius` instead of °C

Comment: @samcarter: thanks a lot, that was it! Wow, how did you figure that out?! That somehow seemed to happen when I originally copied the title out of the PDF into JabRef. Regarding the degree sign: `$^\circ$`works, `\textcelsius` doesn't. Do I need a package for the latter?

Comment: @Wolfson I read the warnings in .log file to figure that out. Sometime they are helpful :) It was complaining about unknown unicode characters, so I had a closer look at the missing characters.

Comment: @samcarter: I should have a closer look at the .log file as well ;) Would you write your solution as an answer so that I can accept it? The only point left for me is to solve how to change all ° signs with '$^\circ$'. I tried `\DeclareSourcemap{   \maps[datatype=bibtex]{map[overwrite]{      \step[fieldsource=title, fieldset=title,match={°},replace={$^\circ$}]}}}` but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Wolfson would http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/97658/36296 solve your degree problem?

Comment: @samcarter: that works, thank you very much! Thanks to you I can leave now and really enjoy my weekend :)

Comment: @Wolfson Have a nice weekend!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking into the error messages in the log files, one can find there

> ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ﬁ (U+FB01)
>   (inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

this pretty much already tells the solution. There seems to be a character, which is not suitable as input for the bibliography, more precisely the glyph `ﬁ` which represents a ligature of f and i. To solve this simply delete the symbol and retype f and i as individual letters.